# Click on all the result links

Tags: java, selenium

Scenario: Go to Yahoo.com search for hotmail and click on all the search pages one at a time.

My code: It just prints the link of the result pages. Is there a way to click pages 2,3,4 while there is no page left?

```
public class QAJob {

    @Test
    public void jobSearch(){
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://yahoo.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("uh-search-box")).sendKeys("hotmail");
        driver.findElement(By.id("uh-search-button")).click();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //scroll down
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)", "");

        List<WebElement> result_pages=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pagination')]//a[contains(@title,'')]"));

        for (WebElement e: result_pages){

            Actions action= new Actions(driver);

            WebElement search_results=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pagination')]//a[contains(@title,'')]"));
            System.out.println(e.getAttribute("outerHTML"));    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `all the search pages one at a time`? Multiple clicks simultaneously?

Comment: I do not understand your issue well, what I understood that you can not click the link? just use this link of code inside your for loop: e.click()

Comment: I can find the xpath of page 2,3,4 and hard code it, rather I want to be able to click on page 2, then page 3, then the next page so that I do not have to hardcode the xpath,, multiple clicks simultaneously.

Comment: So don't click on index buttons, click `Next` button on each iteration

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to "click on next button on each iteration", I can only think of finding a link using findElementBy and then clicking on that specific link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Selenium you can use the class name to find the element, in your case, the `next` link has the class `next`, so you need something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("next").click();
```

To get to the next page.

Fox example this script print all the links (up to page `MAX_PAGES`):

```
    int MAX_PAGES = 3;
    driver.get("https://yahoo.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("uh-search-box")).sendKeys("hotmail");
    driver.findElement(By.id("uh-search-button")).click();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PAGES; i++) {
        for (WebElement link : driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h3.title > a"))) {
            System.out.println("Title: " + link.getText() + " link" + link.getAttribute("href"));
        }
        driver.findElement(By.className("next")).click();
    }
```

You can change the `MAX_PAGES` variable to go further, or if you prefer to get all pages, you can catch the `NotSuchElementException` that selenium will throw when we reach the last page.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I was able to use your solution tweak it a little bit and use it.